# react-router full path argument

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to do something with React Router and I can't seem to find a way to do it. I am using React Router 4.2.0.

I have some routes that looks like this:

```
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Projects}/>
        <Route path="/editor/:path" component={Editor}/>
      </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
```

When I am on the page */editor*, I would like to get the *path* argument with all the text that is put after even if it has '/' in it.

So if I am going to the page */editor/one/two* path argument will be *one/two*.
If I am going to the page */editor/one/two/three* path argument will be *one/two/three*.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

React router uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for path matching.

Checking the path-to-regexp docs, you see that the library offers the option to match [one-to-many parameters with a `+` prefix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#one-or-more):

```
var re = pathToRegexp('/:foo+')
// keys = [{ name: 'foo', delimiter: '/', optional: false, repeat: true }]

re.exec('/bar/baz')
//=> ['/bar/baz', 'bar/baz']
```

---

In other words, **`/editor/:path+`** matches `/editor/one/two/three`, and argument `path` would be `one/two/three`.